# Expect to multiple process in Tcl with Regex

Tags: regex, tcl, expect, spawn, multiple-processes

I am trying to spawn 2 process at a same time with expect and sending commands simultaneously.

```
spawn telnet $IP1 $Cons1
set id1 $spawn_id
set spawns(1) $spawn_id
set logfile($spawn_id) [open "./$IP1-$Cons1-logs.txt" a]

spawn telnet $IP2 $Cons2
set id2 $spawn_id
set spawns(2) $spawn_id
set logfile($spawn_id) [open "./$IP2-$Cons2-logs.txt" a]


trace add variable expect_out(buffer) write log_by_trace
expect -i spawns(1)  "]"
expect -i spawns(2) "]"
send -i spawns(1) "\r\r\r"
send -i spawns(2) "\r\r\r"
expect -i spawns(1) ">"
expect -i spawns(2) ">"
send -i spawns(1) "sometext\r"
expect -i spawns(1) {
         #Here, match itself is not happening. Does it has anything to do with '-i spawn(1)'
        -re {This\s+is\s+sample(\d).*info\s+(\w{3})} {}
        timeout {puts "timeout happened"}
}
#Here, i am getting no such element for the below 2 statements and 
#there is no such output in expect_out(buffer)
puts $expect_out(buffer)
set x $expect_out(1,string)
set y $expect_out(2,string)
puts $x;
puts $y
send -i spawns(2) "sometext\r"
expect -i spawns(2) {
        -re {This\s+is\s+sample(\d).*info\s+(\w{3})} {}
        timeout {puts "timeout happened"}
}
set slot $expect_out(1,string)
set card_state $expect_out(2,string)
 set x $expect_out(1,string)
set y $expect_out(2,string)
puts $x;
puts $y
```

I am not able to get the match for the regex and there is not content in

```
put $expect_out(buffer)
```

The data I am matching is as follows,

```
This is sample-2(1), info ACT
```

I am trying to get the value '2' and 'ACT' from this match.

Do I have to give it specific to the particular spawn process like I did for `expect` and `send` ? If yes, how to do so ?

Thanks

Comment: can you post what the data you're matching against is?

Comment: I have updated my question with the data i am matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex isn't trying to match the`-2(` and `)` around the digit at all. You could perhaps match them with this regex:

```
This\s+is\s+sample[^(]+\((\d)\).*info\s+(\w{3})
```

`[^(]+` matches anything except opening parens, `\(` is to match the opening paren and `\)` the closing paren.